# Change Chrome's tab look and feel

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension. I want to be able to seperate tabs. I was wondering if there is anyway I can either put space in between tabs or put some small picture in between tabs.

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: What about changing the shape of the tab?

Comment: No, there's no way.